# Дискорд бот на Disnake. Как сделать кнопку неактивной, после нажатия?

Tags: python, бот, discord, disnake

Пишу бота дискорд на Disnake.
Как правильно будет добавить disabled в код, чтобы кнопки были неактивными, после нажатия на них?

[image: После нажатия кнопка до сих пор активна]

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def buttons(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
    await inter.response.send_message(
        embed = disnake.Embed( title="Заголовок", description="Описание", color=0x992d22),
        components=[
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Кнопка1", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="button1"),
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Кнопка2", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="button2"),
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Кнопка3", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="button3"),
    ],
)

@bot.listen("on_button_click")
async def help_listener(inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):

    if inter.component.custom_id == "button1":
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Заголовок Кнопки1", description="Описание Кнопки1", color=0x992d22)
        await inter.response.edit_message(embed=embed)

    elif inter.component.custom_id == "button2":
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Заголовок Кнопки2", description="Описание Кнопки2", color=0x992d22)
        await inter.response.edit_message(embed=embed)

    elif inter.component.custom_id == "button3":
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Заголовок Кнопки3", description="Описание Кнопки3", color=0x992d22)
        await inter.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

каждый калл бек переписать пример :

```
    if inter.component.custom_id == "button1":
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Заголовок Кнопки1", description="Описание Кнопки1", color=0x992d22)
        components=[
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Кнопка1",disabled = True, style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="button1"),
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Кнопка2", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="button2"),
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Кнопка3", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="button3"),
    ]

        await inter.response.edit_message(embed=embed, components = components)
```

если что то не понятно пиши мне в дискорд( maloletka777 )

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `если что то не понятно пиши мне` — чем обещать скорее всего невыполнимое (ведь вряд ли вы лет, например, через десять будете готовы заняться обещанными личными консультациями), лучше изложите прямо в тексте ответа всё что считаете нужным для понимания вашего ответа читающими.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен в правильности того, что я сейчас напишу, но попробуйте так. (При изменении сообщения, изменяется только то, что мы укажем.)

```
components = [
disnake.ui.Button(label="Название кнопки", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, disabled=True, custom_id="Польз ид")
]
await inter.response.edit_message(components=components)
```